# python: float number like integer

Tags: python, floating-point

I try convert a float to int when the number don't have decimals.

[I make this](http://ideone.com/bw1MYG)

```
from math import modf

def float_like_int(n):
    if abs(modf(n)[0]) < 1e-6:
        return int(n)
return n

print float_like_int(10.1)
print float_like_int(10.00001)
print float_like_int(10.000001)
print float_like_int(10.0)
```

exist a standard function or a more general way ? (without 1e-6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following is a bit more readable than your version:

```
def float_like_int(n):
    if round(n, 6) == round(n):
        return int(round(n))
    return n
```

Note that this does have a slightly different meaning than your function, since it would also round something like `9.9999999` to `10`.

Answer (score 3):

Those approach that you are using trys to make a number integer if a fractional part is less than 1e-6  (0.000001 ). This means if you have a number 4.000001, (which is float actually) your function will throw away fractional part. You can change 1e-6 to another value and those numbers, which meet your criteria will be converted to *int*.

Here is my code without any extra modules imported. This code will not throw away any fractional part.

```py
def Func(a):
    if (a * 10) % 10 == 0:
        return int(a)
    else:
        return a
f = 4.03
print Func(23.45)
print Func(f)
print Func(2.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is more natural?

```
def float_like_int(n):
    if int(n) == float(n):
        return int(n)
    else:
        return float(n)
```

Comment: It seems like 14.00006 shall be treated as 14, as it is close enough.

Comment: @glglgl: That's not true: float(14.00006) != int(14.00006)

Comment: If you want rounding, an answer with `round()` like F.J's makes the best sense. I was thinking he meant he didn't by "(without 1e-6)".

Comment: @sharth Right, but `abs(modf(14.0000006)[0]) < 1e-6`. So your solution is not the same as the OP's. (Sorry, I forgot two `0`s in my previous comment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
def isWhole(x):
    if(x%1 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: `x.is_integer()` is simpler. :-)